# BigQuery csv load from GCS fails due to permission issues

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload data from a CSV file in Google Storage to a BigQuery table.

After hitting the create button in the 'Create Table' settings of the BQ UI, I get the following error:

```
Error executing job
Access Denied: File gs://[...]/[...].csv: Access Denied
```

I set up both the BQ organization and dataset, as well as the CS bucket. There is only one other person working on the project.

The following documentation does not really point me to the right settings:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#required_permissions

I would really appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Which permissions do you have over the project?

Comment: Hi, in the 'Permissions' settings of the 'Storage browser' for the relevant bucket, there is the role 'Storage Legacy Bucket Owner'. 

This includes
- Editors of project: [...] and
- Owners of project: [...]

The name of this project is the one that contains the dataset to be used for storing the csv file in BigQuery.

Comment: The mostly likely scenario I'd imagine for this sort of failure is that you're running the BigQuery job as the project's default service account, and that service account perhaps doesn't have access to the data, or alternately that service account isn't scoped for access to GCS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me again to the access roles. I added 'BigQuery Data Owner' and Cloud Storage 'Storage Admin' for myself and now it works! THANKS!!!